# Copy referenced project's dependency .dll's to target output with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll

I have an application project *App.csproj* which has a reference to *BaseLib.csproj*.  *BaseLib* uses some DevExpress third party libraries and contains references to the thrid party libraries.  *App* does not directly use the DevExpress libraries so does not need a direct reference to the third party libraries.  This is the reference list for *BaseLib*.

[image: Reference list of BaseLib]

When I build the application, I want the DevExpress libraries to be copied over to the target directory so it will successfully execute.  I don't want to introduce a build event since it is something else to maintain - I'd like the maintenance to be localized to the *BaseLib* project.

This partially works now.  I have 7 references and 5 of the .dll's will copy over (NavBar and Office2007 does not).  The difference is that *BaseLib.dll* contains these statements for the 5 that do copy but they are not present for the 2 that do not (output from *ildasm*).

```
.assembly extern 'DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v13.1.Core'
{
  .publickeytoken = (B8 8D 17 54 D7 00 E4 9A )                         // ...T....
  .ver 13:1:4:0
}
.assembly extern 'DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v13.1'
{
  .publickeytoken = (B8 8D 17 54 D7 00 E4 9A )                         // ...T....
  .ver 13:1:4:0
}
```

So, how can I get the other 2 included?  All the settings are the same in the properties tab.
The other 2 were added at a later time if that makes a difference.

Just to note, this is a followup to these two questions ([Copying a DLL's dependencies in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043913/copying-a-dlls-dependencies-in-visual-studio/12076542#12076542) and [Msbuild doesn't copy references (dlls) if using project dependencies in solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132243/msbuild-doesnt-copy-references-dlls-if-using-project-dependencies-in-solution)).

Comment: MSBuild cannot copy assemblies that are not referenced with a .assembly directive.  That's where it ends, do something [like this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q272041).  Also the place to get help from the vendor.

Comment: BaseLib is my assembly.  I just don't know how to generate the other two .assembly directives in BaseLib.dll.  Visual Studio should do this based on the reference list, yes?  Thanks.

Comment: You probably can't.  They are the kind of assemblies that quack like "if it is available then I'll use it".  Like plug-ins.  So the C# compiler never actually sees a type from the assembly being used, plug-ins use reflection.  Easier for the library vendor, they have less ways that their code will fail to compile.  Not so easy on a programmer that bought the library because they don't want to know how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little more information, I was able to determine that 2 missing .dlls had components that were only referenced via XAML and not in code behind.  If I added a reference in C# code, then the .assembly directive would be added for that module.