# How to automatically include config file that dll depends on to your project?

Tags: dll, dependencies

I created a set of tools that I want to use as a dll.  I seem to be using the same code in each of my programs.  Part of it is NLog.  But it needs an NLog.config.  When I add this new dll I created as a reference, how can I make sure that the NLog.config gets added to my project as part of the dll dependency?

Comment: I found this. Does anyone else have any other ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043913/copying-a-dlls-dependencies-in-visual-studio