# Load a DLL with dependencies in Python

Tags: python, c++, dll, loadlibrary

I have `proj1.dll` that has a dependency to another DLL, `proj2.dll`. I compiled `proj1.dll` against the import library that was output by the compiler when compiling `proj2.dll` in VS2013. I also exported the public functions I am interested in using. So now I have two separate DLLs that all conform to the 'cdll' standard.

I want to use `proj1.dll` in Python but I am running into the following issue:

```
import ctypes

# Crashes saying no entry point for "some_func" in proj2.dll
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\myfolder\proj1.dll")

ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\myfolder\proj2.dll") # Loads fine
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\myfolder\proj1.dll") # Loads fine if proj2 is loaded first
```

Calling into this DLL from Python previously worked when I built `proj2` as a static library and linked against it in `proj1`. The two DLLs exist in the same folder. I even attempted adding the folder's path to my PATH environment variable to see if this was a pathing issue but nothing changed.

I was under the assumption that Windows would load `proj1.dll` and then load the dll's dependencies. Am I wrong? Does the caller (Python) have to load the dependency DLLs first? Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Is `myfolder` in your path? You might want to check your `proj1.dll` to confirm it includes the dependency. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency

Comment: What is the *Python* version? What is the error?

Comment: @CristiFati I'm not sure OP is still around to answer your question. I did open the bounty because I have a very similar question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61717476/loading-python-module-depending-on-dll-not-next-to-it) and thought that a more complete answer to this question would also answer mine (I would have closed my question as a duplicate had a good answer been posted here). Feel free to check the other question and asks there, and maybe I'll do it the other way around.

Comment: @Holt: So, this is a different problem than the one from the pointed question.

Answer (score 5):

You need to make sure your environment path contains the path to the dependencies. This will work.

```
import os
from ctypes import *

path_to_deps = "C:\\myfolder"
os.environ['PATH'] = path_to_deps + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']
d = CDLL("C:\myfolder\proj2.dll")
```

Update:

In [python 3.8 update notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html) the call `os.add_dll_directory(path)` has been added and is used for specifying dll directories to search in.

Answer (score 3):

Listing [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

Given the time the question was asked, *Python 3.8* can be ruled out (but [[SO]: PyWin32 and Python 3.8.0 (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632354/4788546) might still be interesting).
Basically, it's the same as [[SO]: Can't import dll module in Python (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333711/4788546).

For *.dll* loading generics, [[SO]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546) might contain useful info.

Now, the question isn't exactly a *MCVE* or *REPREX* ([[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), but I assume that if it was, the answer would probably be obvious, and therefore no need for the question :)

#### Investigation

The error is ***ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND*** (*127*, *0x7F*).

**Note**: **A *.dll* is loaded only after all its dependencies have been successfully loaded (recursively)**. If one of the dependencies fails, the failure is propagated all the way to the top, and the (original) *.dll* load fails with that error.

What happens (automatically) in the 2 cases:

- **Success**:

  1. *proj2* is found and attempted to be loaded. It succeeds
  2. *proj1* is found attempted to be loaded

     1. As it depends on *proj2*, that one is attempted to be loaded 1<sup>st</sup>
     2. *proj2* is already in memory (from *#1.*)
     3. Functions from *proj2* that are required by *proj1* are searched in *proj2*. They are all found

     As a consequence, this step (*#2.*) also succeeds
- **Failure**:

  1. *proj1* is found attempted to be loaded

     1. As it depends on *proj2*, that one is attempted to be loaded 1<sup>st</sup>
     2. *proj2* was found and loaded (if it wasn't, the error would have been *ERROR_**MOD**_NOT_FOUND*)
     3. Functions from *proj2* that are required by *proj1* are searched in *proj2*. Apparently, (at least) one, is not found and the program crashes

From the above, one can only conclude that **there is a *proj2.dll* somewhere in the *%PATH%* and that one is being automatically loaded by the *OS* when loading *proj1.dll***.
It isn't *C:\myfolder\proj2.dll*. It might be an older version that doesn't export the required function, or another one totally unrelated.

I managed to reproduce the crash with 2 simple (dependent) *.dll*s and an *.exe* (if required, I'll also post the code):

[image: img00]

The (simplest) solution is to **add "*C:\myfolder*" which is *proj2.dll* (the right)'s directory to %PATH%**, before loading *proj1.dll*. Check [[MS.Learn]: Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/Dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order), and bear in mind the following aspects:

- **Appending it** (at the end) **will not do**, as the wrong *.dll* *dir* is already in *%PATH%* (before the right's one), and the wrong *.dll* will be found (and loaded) 1<sup>st</sup>
- You'll have to add it **before** the wrong one's *dir* (or even better: remove the wrong one's *dir* from %PATH% altogether). To check where it is, use (in the *cmd*) terminal:

  ```bat
  where proj2.dll
  ```
- Since I don't know where the wrong *.dll* *dir* position is in the *%PATH%*, adding the right *.dll* *dir* at the beginning of *%PATH%* would be *OK*. Personally, I don't consider prepending directories before *Win* system ones a good practice
- If however *proj2.dll* is located under "*%SystemRoot%\System32*", you'll have to remove (or rename) it (the file)

Anyway, *%PATH%* altering can be done either:

- Before starting *Python*:

  ```bat
  set PATH=C:\myfolder;%PATH%
  ```
- From *Python* itself:

  ```py
  os.environ["PATH"] = "C:\myfolder;" + os.environ["PATH"]
  ```

  For *Python 3.8*, check the related *URL* at the beginning of the answer

Might also want to check:

- [[SO]: Discover missing module using command-line ("DLL load failed" error) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74883130/4788546)
- [[SO]: Why does adding multiprocessing prevent python from finding my compiled c program? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75035737/4788546)
- [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Build settings need to be changed for your project..

See if this helps: [Copying a DLL's dependencies in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1043913/1615916)