# Analog of `os.add_dll_directory` for Linux

Tags: python, path, shared-libraries

I am trying to load a `.so` library in Python using `ctypes`. This library has many files in `/home/me/my_library`. When I load

```
from ctypes import *
lib = CDLL('/home/me/my_library/main.so')
```

I get

```
OSError: not_main.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Note that the error is with `not_main.so` and not with `main.so`. All the files are within `/home/me/my_library`. I think the problem is that I have to add the path to this library, which in Windows can be done using `os.add_dll_directory`. How would I do this in Linux? Is there a cross-platform way of doing this?

**Note** I have tried with `os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/home/me/my_library/'` but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand until **python 3.8** on both **Linux** and **Windows** to add search path you would need to add it to the `PATH` env variable:

```py
if not os.environ['PATH'].__contains__('/path/to/dll_or_so'):
  os.environ['PATH'] = '/path/to/dll_or_so' + os.pathsep + os.environ['PATH']
```

Starting from **python 3.8** this approach doesn't seem to work on **Windows** and new function was introduced to solve this task: [os.add_dll_directory(path)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.add_dll_directory)

Thus in your case (**Linux**) you should modify `os.environ['PATH']`

[See previous answer on similar topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734176/load-a-dll-with-dependencies-in-python)

Comment: I don't think it will work in Linux. You should put the list of the directories to search in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable.